# AWS S3 , drop existing connection when upload large file

Tags: python, amazon-s3

The script can upload small files, a few MBs, but not working for large files. I am trying to upload a file with 7GB, this will cause a socket error:

socket.error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the re
mote host

```
s3_connection = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket = s3_connection.get_bucket('yardi-backup')
key = boto.s3.key.Key(bucket, os.path.basename(latest_file))
key.set_contents_from_filename(latest_file)
sys.exit(0)

with open(latest_file, 'r') as f:
    #key.send_file(f)
    key.set_contents_from_file(f)
```

Comment: Use the multipart upload API for large objects (5 GB to 5 TB).

Answer (score 0):

With a single PUT operation, you can upload objects only up to 5 GB in size. For files more then 5GB up to 5TB, you should use multipart upload API.

Following [gist](https://gist.github.com/dondoco7/2237612) provides a nice example on multipart upload to S3 using boto3.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadingObjects.html